# Post loop for all taxonomy terms

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, loop, taxonomy

I currently have a custom taxonomy set up called `development-category` at the moment, if I want to set up a posts loop for each of these taxonomies, I'm having to do it as follows:

```
<?php $hotels_loop = new WP_Query( array( 'development-category' => 'hotels', 'post_type' => 'developments' ) ); ?>

    <ul class="sector-menu-sub-menu">       
        <?php while ( $hotels_loop->have_posts() ) : $hotels_loop->the_post(); ?>

            <?php the_title(); ?>//etc etc

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>


<?php $leisure_loop = new WP_Query( array( 'development-category' => 'leisure', 'post_type' => 'developments' ) ); ?>

    <ul class="sector-menu-sub-menu">       
        <?php while ( $leisure_loop->have_posts() ) : $leisure_loop->the_post(); ?>

            <?php the_title(); ?>//etc etc

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>


<?php $commercial_loop = new WP_Query( array( 'development-category' => 'commercial', 'post_type' => 'developments' ) ); ?>

    <ul class="sector-menu-sub-menu">       
        <?php while ( $commercial_loop->have_posts() ) : $commercial_loop->the_post(); ?>

            <?php the_title(); ?>//etc etc

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>


//etc etc
```

This works, but I'm having to set up a loop for each taxonomy term, in this instance got a loop for the `hotels` taxonomy term, the `leisure` taxonomy term and the `commercial` taxonomy term, but I don't want to have to do this for every new taxonomy term I add, and as the site is content managed, it will be managed by the client so they won't be able to do so either. I'm wondering if there's a way too set up a loop for every taxonomy term for the `development-category` taxonomy, so if a new term is added, it will create a new loop as per my code below, if that makes sense? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get all the terms in a custom taxonomy using the following code:

```
$terms = get_terms( 'development-category' );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'development-category' => $term->slug, 'post_type' => 'developments' ) ); ?>
        ....    
    }
}
```

Comment: This can get very expensive